# Iris-wipe shader not properly working

Tags: shaders, hlsl, monogame

I'm working on creating an iris wipe transition, like the ones you see in old cartoons - a fully transparent circle closes on a certain point, leaving a full screen of a solid color. Additionally, the background around the circle fades in from full transparency as well. I decided that shaders would be easier than creating vertices to build the iris effect. I may have been wrong.

**EDIT:** I've made some progress since asking this question - there is now an iris effect, but it opens and closes around a blank `CornflowerBlue` screen before displaying the screen, and the background around the circle is always full transparency.

Shader:

```
sampler TextureSampler : register(s0);
float2 irisCenter;
float radius;
float4 backColor;

float4 PixelShaderFunction(float4 pos : SV_POSITION, float4 color1 : COLOR0, float2 coords: TEXCOORD0) : COLOR0
{
    float4 p = pos;
    float2 c = irisCenter;
    float r = radius;

    float alpha = abs(1 - step(pow(p.x - c.x, 2) + pow(p.y - c.y, 2), r * r));
    return float4(backColor.r, backColor.g, backColor.b, alpha * backColor.a);
}

technique Technique1
{
    pass Pass1
    {
        PixelShader = compile ps_3_0 PixelShaderFunction();
    }
}
```

The `alpha` variable should be deciding if a pixel is inside the circle and should be transparent, or if the pixel is outside the circle and shouldn't be. `irisCenter`, `radius`, and `backColor` are all set on each frame by:

```
public void Draw()
{
    if (isInitialized && (isRunning || dir == EffectDirection.Backward))
    {
        float r = color.R; // / 255f;
        float g = color.G; // / 255f;
        float b = color.B; // / 255f;
        float a = (color.A * currentFadeLevel); // / 255f;

        var irisEffect = GameServices.Effects["IrisEffect"];
        irisEffect.Parameters["irisCenter"].SetValue(irisCenter);
        irisEffect.Parameters["radius"].SetValue(irisRadius);
        irisEffect.Parameters["backColor"].SetValue(new Vector4(r, g, b, a));

        quadRenderer.Render(irisEffect);
    }
}
```

[IrisEffect.cs](http://pastebin.com/ruKTXsd4)

[QuadRenderer.cs](http://pastebin.com/uY0BpJxL)

Instead of behaving as an iris wipe, it first draws a full-screen rectangle for half the effect, and then a full-screen `Color.CornflowerBlue` rectangle (I guess the quad from `QuadRenderer` isn't drawing with transparency). I'm not sure what's wrong as I'm new to HLSL.

Question 1: How can I get the coordinates of the current pixel being processed by the shader?

Question 2: What am I doing wrong?

Question 3: How do I draw the rest of the quad transparently?

Comment: I've found a bit of a solution - at least, some headway, with [this](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/109429/34552) answer.

Comment: Maybe this answer might give you some pointers: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/83853/how-to-implement-color-changing-fragment-shader/83871#83871

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, turns out I had my draw calls in the wrong order. Drawing the effect last, after everything else in the scene, solves all my issues. Also, the complicated vertice trickery in `QuadRenderer` can be replaced with a simple call to a helper method I have that draws rectangles of arbitrary colors.